# make images on front page slide using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I want to have horizontal transitioning of pictures every 5 seconds or so and when the move is over, it pauses. I don't what this feature is called. But if you [look](http://consumerguide.com/) at these [websites](http://evoximages.com/), you might know guess what I mean. There are three or four dots in the bottom and user can click there to automatically see a particular image.

is this feature possible with jquery? I am using Twitter bootstrap 3 for my application.
I am looking for resources where I can find implementation/code for this behavior.
I am a beginner with jquery.

Comment: it is called a carousel or slider.  http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-carousel-mac-stack-demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A carousel is what you're looking for, you can find it here:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel